# RavenDB map/reduce index for two levels deep nested relationship documents

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I have Job documents with the structure below.  These Job documents potentially have same crew members.  I'm trying to create a map/reduce index to compute the total number of unique crew members for a list of jobs, and I keep getting the total count instead of total unique count.

Here is the map/reduce index I've tried, which returned total count instead of unique count.

```
    Map = jobs => from job in jobs
                  from crew in job.Crews
                  from member in crew.Members
                  select new { UserID = member.UserName, Count = 1 }

    Reduce = results => from result in results.Distinct()
                        group result by 0 into g
                        select new { UserID = "", g.Sum(x => x.Count) }


{
    "Name": "Planetary Laser",
    "Crews": [
        {
            "Name": "Laser Team 1",
            "Members": [
                {
                    "UserName": "vader@empire.com",
                },
                {
                    "UserName": "uno@empire.com",
                },
                {
                    "UserName": "dos@empire.com",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            "Name": "Laser Team 2",
            "Members": [
                {
                    "UserName": "emporer@empire.com",
                },
                {
                    "UserName": "bfett@empire.com",
                },
                {
                    "UserName": "dos@empire.com",
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
Map = jobs => from job in jobs
                  from crew in job.Crews
                  from member in crew.Members
                  select new { UserID = member.UserName, Count = 1 }
Reduce = results => from result in results
                        group result result by result.UserId into g
                        select new { UserID = g.Key, g.Sum(x => x.Count) }
```

This index gives you the total number of jobs per user. And the total number of users in the index is the number of distinct users.